# Exit Value 1 when returning 0

Tags: c, exit

I've searched up and down Google and I cannot find a reason why this code is still failing.

```
void returnSeven();

int main() {
  returnSeven();
  return 0;
}

void returnSeven(){
  printf("Hello");
}
```

It builds properly but gives me the

> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 21ms)

error. Any possible ideas how to get rid of this? I've run it from command line and it gives me the same error. I've even had a friend run it and it seemed to work just fine for him. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: language tag? We can't really give an answer without knowing what language we're in...

Comment: Side note: `returnSeven` is a terrible name for a function that doesn't return seven.

Comment: You might want to specify IDE, compiler, and OS because normally this wouldn't occur.

Comment: Ha, sorry about that. I was playing around with different bits of code and didn't bother to change the name.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 7.1.1, Cygwin gcc compiler, and Windows 7.

Comment: Ah, are you running the project remotely? There is [a bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=190318) on that.

Comment: I am not. Running it directly from my computer.

Comment: Code is valid, script that checkes exit codes is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code are ok after adding `#include <stdio.h>`. So, have you add that line in your code?
In the C programming language, if you haven't define `printf`, it can also be compiled just with a warning like this : `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]`

Comment: Sorry about the late response, but I do have #include <stdio.h> in my code, as well as #include <stdlib.h> just because. So far, everyone I've asked says my code is correct, so I'm beginning to think it's something wrong with the compiler or just my computer.

Comment: ok, could you tell me which program put this line in to your screen? I mean that line: `RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 21ms)` Is that zsh or other shell?

Comment: @user1273124 maybe you can try an other shell to avoid shell's bug. :D